# Sending Bulk Emails using PHP

Tags: php, email, execution, bulk

I have to send mails to all users in the site when a new user joins.
My problem is the script stops execution after sending around 400 mails.
I have set the set_time_limit to 0. And also I am giving sleep(2) after sending 10 mails.

What may be the reason behind this issue.Any solution for this problem . Is there any better method to send bulk emails?

Thanks in Advance

Rose

Answer (score 2):

The way we do it is with the help of cron.

We (at our company) split up the userlist in blocks of 50 addresses. These blocks are put in a table in the database (with data that links this block to the e-mail data (headers, body, ..).

Through a cron.php file, which is triggered every 5 minutes or so, the system grabs the first available block in the database that needs to be sent and sends out the emails.

Comment: I am also using cron jobs ,which is set to execute twice in day.
I cant follow the above method because 

1.There may be more than one new user in the site and this list changes from time to time.

2.I need to update a field(new user flag to zero) corresponding to each new users after sending that user details to all others users in the site

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was down to memory usage, how are you sending them, can you provide any code?

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is running in [safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode), `set_time_limit` will have no effect. If you *must* run PHP in safe mode, you can modify the default time limit using the configuration directive `max_execution_time`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your script stops. But you also asked for better ways to send bulk emails. I found that using an email package gives you much more control than the built-in PHP mail command. [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) is a very good one.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a task queue. When your web application wants to send an email, it adds it to a database of tasks and a separate daemon processes each one. This means, you can set an email to be sent to every member of the website and your daemon will send each one every 2-4 seconds. See the [Kohana task queue module](http://github.com/jonnyjon/Task-Queue) (PHP), [Delayed_job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) (Ruby), and [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) (Python) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a new answer because this one doesn't relate to my previous one.

I was wondering: where exactly do you set `set_time_limit` to `0`? I mean, is it in php.ini, .htaccess, or from a php file with ini_set().

Is it possible that this value gets overridden?