# Sending Notification Emails in PHP

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending Bulk Emails using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938037/sending-bulk-emails-using-php)

Is there a service out there that can handle sending emails constantly through PHP without issue? We're looking to send out 500+ emails a day or more and are worried about using the built in mail functions of PHP.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://swiftmailer.org/. Refer to the Related Questions section at the bottom right of this page, it has lots of good information.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with the built-in mail functions, and 500 e-mails a day is almost no load at all.  PHP simply executes your configured MTA executable, such as sendmail.

However, I'd recommend using a better mail API such as [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).  This will enable you to build e-mails with HTML, attachments, and such much easier than trying to generate your own MIME messages.

For larger mail volumes, I would recommend using a 3rd party, such as [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) (or one of the many, many others).  They're very good at keeping you off blacklists for spam and such.

Answer (score 1):

500 emails/day really isn't that many. You have several options:

1. Send the mail yourself, from your server. You could use third party libraries to handle the multitude of options. Swiftmailer, PHPMailer etc or roll your own. Sending from your own servers, you will need to manage reverse DNS, SPF records etc and (assuming you're on Linux) will become quite well acquainted with Postfix et al.
2. Optionally you can use third-party services, such as http://sendgrid.com/ or http://aws.amazon.com/ses/. These are essentially pay-as-you-go mail servers with nice simple APIs. This can help with a lot of the heavy lifting involved in maintaining reliable mail servers. This gets complicated when you're sending thousands of emails per day. Throttling, queueing, load balancing etc.
3. Another option, if you're doing eMarketing is to use a service such as Mailchimp or Campaign Monitor. These will do all proofing, sending, throttling and reporting for you for a one-time fee.

Comment: +1 for a good answer.  I thought I would just comment and say that SendGrid may be find for most folks, but I've had numerous minor issues with them.  Nothing show-stopping, but their servers will often claim our username/password are wrong, but simply re-trying works fine.  Their support folk are not knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php's mail() function without any issue. but most of the shared hosting servers do not allow you send large volume emails.. You can use third party SMTP for this..